# Подскажите HTML редактор с отображением результата в реальном времени без обновления страницы

Tags: html, редактор

Подскажите HTML редактор с отображением результата в реальном времени без обновления страницы.
Когда-то наблюдал видео в ютубе, редактор кода - слева, результат отображается справа моментально.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, для таких целей вполне подойдет Brackets, он не только html редактор, также можете спокойно настроить его под себя. В нём есть функция "Live Preview" благодаря которой не обязательно обновлять страницу при внесении изменений в html/css код.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Dreamweaver. -- Можно одновременно писать код и видеть результат.

CoffeeCup HTML Editor. -- В одной закладке пишешь код, в другой видишь результат.